# Type Constructor as Return Type

Tags: scala, haskell, return-type, algebraic-data-types, type-constructor

In Scala, I can define an [Algebraic Data Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689951/writing-algebraic-data-type-in-scala):

```
scala> sealed trait Maybe[A]
defined trait Maybe

scala> case class Just[A](x: A) extends Maybe[A]
defined class Just

scala> case object NothingHere extends Maybe[Nothing]
defined object NothingHere
```

It's possible to return a function, `f`, with a return type of `Maybe[A]`.

```
scala> def f[A](x: A): Maybe[A] = Just(x)
f: [A](x: A)Maybe[A]
```

However, it's also possible to specify that a `Just[A]` is returned.

```
scala> def f[A](x: A): Just[A] = Just(x)
f: [A](x: A)Just[A]
```

Now I'll do the similar exercise in Haskell:

```
Prelude> data Option a = None | Some a deriving Show
Prelude> let f x = Some x :: Option Int
Prelude> f 10
Some 10
```

But, I can't set a return type of a *type constructor*.

```
Prelude> let f x = Some x :: Some Int

<interactive>:10:21:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class `Some'
    A data constructor of that name is in scope; did you mean DataKinds?
Prelude> let f x = None :: None
```

Is the simple difference that Scala's `Just` is a class, i.e. a legitimate return type? Whereas, in Haskell, a *type constructor* cannot be a return type?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference is how Scala chose to implement ADTs.  Scala uses case classes that extend a trait in an OOP style, so each case is its own type, whereas Haskell just has multiple constructors for the same type.  Since they aren't separate types but essentially just separate functions, you can't distinguish them at the type level.  There are extensions that give you some ability to make that type level distinction, but it won't be the same thing as what Scala has.  And trying to fit Haskell's type system into Scala's type system is probably not the best of ideas.

In short, Scala approximates ADTs using a form of inheritance, whereas Haskell just has ADTs.

Comment: There are extensions that give you _similar_ ability, but it's quite crucial that Haskell has no subclassing, so you positively can't do _the same thing_..

Comment: @leftaroundabout Changed the wording a bit to make it more clear that I was referring to extensions that let you distinguish constructors at the type level, but that it isn't what Scala has.  Think it makes it more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

bhelkir and leftaroundabout have pointed out why you can't do this exactly in Haskell: there is no notion of subtypes.

But note that with ADTs there are often alternatives that allow you achieve the same effect.  In this case, one candidate technique would be to use [the `Void` type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/void-0.7/docs/Data-Void.html) in conjunction with `Either`:

```
import Data.Void

f :: Int -> Either Void Int
f x = Right x
```

`Void` is a type that has no defined values.  Therefore if you see the type `Either Void a`, that means that since there's no value `x :: Void` nobody can ever construct any value of the form `Left x :: Either Void a`.  (The exception is if `x` is a guaranteed nonterminating value, but [we customarily ignore that possibility](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/#moral-correctness).)

That means that an `Either Void a` is always of the form `Right a`, so for example, you can write this function:

```
-- | Extract the @a@ from @Either Void a@.
extract :: Either Void a -> a
extract (Left x) = absurd x
extract (Right a) = a
```

The `absurd x` there works basically like this: since `x :: Void` that means that there can never actually be a value for `x`, then `absurd :: Void -> a`, given its type, is a function that is impossible to ever call.  The way the type system works this means that it can claim to return any type at all that the caller expects.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131856/whats-the-absurd-function-in-data-void-useful-for) for some more discussion (though maybe a bit advanced).

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not just return `a` directly?

Comment: What I meant is that, if you exclude bottoms, `Either Void a` is isomorphic to `a`. Why go to all that trouble?