# Is ::[Int] the same as List[Int]?

Tags: list, scala, cons

```
scala> val w = new ::[Int](4,Nil)
w: scala.collection.immutable.::[Int] = List(4)

scala> val x = List[Int](4)
x: List[Int] = List(4)
```

What is the difference between these two expressions? Is `::[Int](4)` an instance of `List[int]`, since both `::[Int](4)` and `List[Int](4)` yield `List(4)`?

Comment: because both `::` and `Nil` extend the trait `List`.

Comment: I would recommend you to take any basic scala tutorial, especially because it seems you haven't done the canonical example of how to create the **List** by yourself.

Comment: Unlike [List](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/collection/immutable/List.html), [::](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/collection/immutable/$colon$colon.html) is not covariant

Answer (score 3):

`::[T]` is one of the **constructors** of the **algebraic data type** `List[T]`. The other one is `Nil`. Consider the following [inductive definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_definition) of a `List`

```
sealed trait List[+T]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing] 
case class ::[T](head: T, tail: List[T]) extends List[T]
```

`::` might look a bit odd as it is purely symbolic name, and in other languages it is sometimes referred as [`Cons`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type). Constructors are the means of making **values** of type `List[T]`, here are a few

```
Nil
::(1, Nil)
::(2, ::(1, Nil))
::(42, ::(2, ::(1, Nil)))
```

These value, being of inductive nature, have a remarkable property of whenever we have one, we always know how to construct the **following** one(s). In other words, inductive values **imply** inductive values. For example, both

```
::(2, ::(1, Nil))
```

and

```
::(51, ::(1, Nil))
```

are implications of `::(1, Nil)` by the power of constructor `::[Int]`.

> Is `::[Int]` the same as `List[Int]`?

Because Scala implements algebraic data types using a [form of inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30623824/5205022), there indeed exists a *is-a-subtype-of* relationship

```
implicitly[::[Int] <:< List[Int]] // ok!
```

whilst there does not exist *equal-to* relationship

```
implicitly[::[Int] =:= List[Int]] // error!
```

However, in my opinion, these subtyping relationships are not the point of algebraic data type, being kind of incidental in Scala. Instead the relationship between a constructor `::[T]` and a type `List[T]` whose values it is constructing, is more analogous to relationship between a *function* and a *type*.

> Is `new ::[Int](4, Nil)` the same as `List[Int](4)`?

They both evaluate to the same value, for example the following passes

```
assert(new ::[Int](4, Nil) == List[Int](4))
```

however the way we arrive at this value is quite different. In the former case we are using directly the constructor of the `List[Int]` ADT, whilst in the latter case we are in fact calling `apply` method on the **companion** object of `trait List[T]`

```
List.apply[Int](4)
```

where `apply` is defined as

```
def apply[A](xs: A*): List[A] = xs.toList
```

Now in practice we rarely have to think about these things. Usually we simply write something like

```
List(4, 2, 42)
```

and be done with it. The "low level" constructor `::` shows its face sometimes during **pattern matching** which is a way of **destructuring** ADTs, for example, here is recursive implementation that gets the sum of elements in a list

```
def sum(l: List[Int]): Int = {
  l match {
    case Nil => 0
    case head :: tail => head + sum(tail)
  }
}

sum(List(1, 2, 42)) 
// res1: Int = 45
```

Answer (score 1):

The `abstract class List` is sealed, so it is only extended by the class `::[+A]`, and the  `object Nil`.

This means, that in order to conform to the `type List[+A]`, an object has to be of `type ::[X]`, where `X` conforms to `A`, or `Nil`, which conforms to `List[Nothing]`.

A value of `type List[Int]` may well be `Nil`, since `List[Nothing]` conforms to `List[Int]`. On the Other hand, you cannot assign `Nil` to a value of `type ::[Int]`, since it is not a `::[_]`.

TL;DR:
Every `::[_]` is a `List[_]`, but not every `List[_]` is a `::[_]`.