# Scala: getting all possible values that a specific type can have

Tags: scala

Given a type `T` is it possible to create a list of all possible values values that type contains (if it is bounded)? For example if `T` is `Boolean` the list should be `Set(True, False)`.

Comment: Are you looking for all values in an algebraic set?

Comment: What do you mean by an "algebraic" set?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something similar to Haskell's `Bounded` typeclass? You can find it in scalaz

```
> val bounded = implicitly[Enum[Boolean]]
bounded: scalaz.Enum[Boolean] = scalaz.std.AnyValInstances$booleanInstance$@108745fc
> (bounded.min |@| bounded.max)(_ |-> _)
res1: Option[List[Boolean]] = Some(List(false, true))
```

You can find references for [Enum](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Enum.html), [Bounded](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Bounded.html) and [Applicative](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Applicative.html). Enjoy.

Note that creating list for all `Int`s can take quite some time...

Comment: Can you explain more why and how this looks? I looked into source and it seems that `allValues = enumFrom minBound` which uses functions for `Enum` and `Bounded`.

Comment: Instances for `Finite` in this package _are_ implemented like this (or equivalently), but a type can be finite without having a natural ordering and thus without being `Enum` or `Bounded`. E.g. a cyclic type which has a "next" operation which eventually returns to the starting point, but no start/end. Or `Complex Int`.

Comment: That is right, thank you! However I couldn't find it in scalaz. If it implemented for scala it would be nice to have reference, if not it is still interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

Not all types are closed. For example, `Boolean` is with all possible values of `Set(True, False)`, but what would the answer be for `Double`?

It sounds like you're looking to define an algebraic type. In Scala, the idiomatic way to do this is with a `sealed trait` and case classes and objects. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689951/writing-algebraic-data-type-in-scala) for more details.

Comment: `Double`s are closed, there's "only" 2^64 of them :-D

Comment: Haha... Fair enough. 