# Optional Fields, ADT, or?

Tags: scala

Given an `A`, which may have optional fields, `a` and `b`:

`case class A(a: Option[Int], b: Option[String])`

I could define `A` as an [Algebraic Data Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689951/writing-algebraic-data-type-in-scala).

However, it would require 4 sub-classes to account for each `None/Option` choice:

```
sealed trait AADT
case class Aa(a: Int) extends AADT
case class Aab(a: Int, b: String) extends AADT
case class Ab(b: String) extends AADT
case object Neither extends AADT
```

I'd argue that this ADT is preferable to the above `A` option, which has `Option` types.

However, this type could quickly get out of hand with 3, 4, etc. fields.

Is there a third way to implement `A`, i.e. not using either my first or second implementation?

Comment: You realized that Option[A] is itself an ADT right?

Comment: My first thought against your proposal would be to argue that Option itself already gives a few useful methods like map, flatMap, filter etc. But on other hand A is a monomorphic.

Comment: One tried way (that is actually pretty boring) is to use `(Option[Int], Option[String])`. But to compensate this boredom I offer a forth option, use a Shapeless coproduct of Int, String, (Int, String) and Neither.

Comment: Have you considered a factory `object` that would return an appropriate class depending on the provided parameters?

Comment: @pedrofurla I don't see how using a `Tuple` is any different than a case class in this instance. Please let me know what advantage you see.

Comment: Tuple2 already exists. But yeah, it's essentially the same thing. But so will any other solution.

Comment: @KevinMeredith You might be interested in this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YScIPA8RbVE, if you are not already familiar with the topic. It requires some Haskell knowledge, which I'd be glad to help if you need (very basic though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Algebraically there is a third option that covers all combination

```
sealed trait A
case class Ao(o: Option[(Int, String)]) extends A //all or none
case class Ae(e: Either[Int, String]) extends A //first or second
```

---

I would definitely choose some sort of ADT if there is a separate domain name for each case.

Optional fields are good for data transferred objects (DTO)

Comment: Good catch! Really liked.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first thing that came to my mind and posting it in the comment section would be hardly readable. It definitely isn't a prettiest solution but might be 'good enough' for OP's case.

```
sealed trait AADT
case class Aa(a: Int) extends AADT
case class Aab(a: Int, b: String) extends AADT
case class Ab(b: String) extends AADT
case object Neither extends AADT

object AADTBuilder {
  def apply() = Neither
  def apply(a: Int) = Aa(a)
  def apply(a: Int, b: String) = Aab(a, b)
  def apply(b: String) = Ab(b)
}
```

And just call `AADTBuilder` with the right parameters.

Comment: I don't think the question is about how to construct but rather how to structure.

Comment: Yeah, I misread that, will leave the answer up as someone might find it handy @pedrofurla